# Why is my pandas dataframe turning into 'None' type?

Tags: python, pandas

I can't see where is my problem, this code worked ok for a very simple example, but when I started working with my real data, I encountered problems.

I am basically extracting certain data from various csv files and trying to eventually combine them in a single dataframe.

The relevant piece of code is below:

```
wavenames = ['W1_', 'W2_', 'W3_']
logs=['log1','log2','log3','log4']

for w in wavenames:
    AllSynt = pd.DataFrame(index=range(6341), columns=['X']+logs)
    AllSynt['X']=z # an array extracted from elsewhere
    print AllSynt.head(3)
    for f in files:
        for l in logs:
            if (f.startswith('Synthetic_'+w)) & (f.endswith(l+'.csv')):
                df = pd.read_csv(path+f,delimiter=',')  
                AllSynt = pd.DataFrame(AllSynt)
                AllSynt = AllSynt.merge(df,how='left',on='X')
                AllSynt = AllSynt.rename(columns = {'Y':l}, inplace = True)
    print '\n', AllSynt.head(5)
```

but this gives me `AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'head'`
(before making sure that the AllSynt is a pandas dataframe at the beginning of the loop, I got the same error (just saying it has no attribute 'merge'). Why is my AllSynt dataframe permanently turning into a `None`?

Comment: There's no need to reassign the results back to the variable when you provide `inplace=True` during `rename` operation. Which is why, these get returned as `None` values.

Comment: Thanks, this helped a bit (all the values are `NaN`, but at least it is a dataframe). But I am still suspicious - as mentioned in the question, the `None` value appeared already at the beginning of the loop before the renaming process. Why was that?

Comment: That was because you had already populated it's colum names while filling only values corresponding to `X` with the predefined array. The elements present in `logs` (*which constituted the column names*) had no values under them so they were naturally being filled by `NaN's`.

Comment: Could you please post your comments as an answer so that I can accept it? Thanks!

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You would need to rewrite the line :

`AllSynt = AllSynt.rename(columns={'Y':l}, inplace=True)`

to simply the following:

```
AllSynt.rename(columns={'Y':l}, inplace=True)  # No assigning with inplace parameter
# (or)
AllSynt = AllSynt.rename(columns={'Y':l})       # assign without inplace parameter
```

When you specify `inplace=True` and want to see it's contents, it would return `None` as they merely mutate the `DF` instead of creating a new copy of it. Basically, you're assigning `None` to the result and hence it complains of the `AttributeError` as it isn't a `pd.DataFrame` object anymore to access it's `.head()` method.

Similar analogy could be observed by doing `list.append()`, `list.sort()` etc operations in pure python while assigning their results to a variable in the same line, which would also return `None` for the same reason as they operate `inplace` by default.

Edit: Added a close parenthesis.